# How to compile clojurescript to nodejs?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Why `cljsbuild` does not compile `gulpfile.js` file properly?

Here is my `project.clj` config:

```
(defproject cljs-selfstudy "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Where I want to learn about clojurescript"
  :url "http://example.com"

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0-alpha2"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2322"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.4-SNAPSHOT"]]

  :source-paths ["src"]


  :cljsbuild {
              :builds [{:id "gulpjs"
                        :source-paths ["src/gulpjs"]
                        :compiler {
                                   :output-to "gulpfile.js"                                   
                                   :optimizations :none
                                   :pretty-print true}}]})
```

Here is my `core.cljs`

```
(ns gulpjs.core
  (:require [cljs.nodejs :as node]))

(def gulp (node/require "gulp"))

(def gulp-livereload (node/require "gulp-livereload"))

(def gulp-markdown (node/require "gulp-markdown"))

(def gulp-watch (node/require "gulp-watch"))

(.task gulp "markdown" 
       #(-> (.source gulp "../markdown-explained")
            (.pipe (gulp-markdown))
            (.pipe (.dest gulp "build/markdown-explained"))))
```

Here is command I used to compile

```
lein cljsbuild once gulpjs

Compiling ClojureScript.
Compiling "gulpfile.js" from ["src/gulpjs"]...
Successfully compiled "gulpfile.js" in 3.316 seconds.
```

But I have this strange output `gulpfile.js`, it doesn't look like node codes at all, why it is so wrong???

```
goog.addDependency("base.js", ['goog'], []);
goog.addDependency("../cljs/core.js", ['cljs.core'], ['goog.string', 'goog.object', 'goog.string.StringBuffer', 'goog.array']);
goog.addDependency("../cljs/nodejs.js", ['cljs.nodejs'], ['cljs.core']);
goog.addDependency("../gulpjs/core.js", ['gulpjs.core'], ['cljs.core', 'cljs.nodejs']);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are targeting nodejs, first thing that you are missing in the compiler options is

```
:target :nodejs
```

Second, if you use `:optimizations :none` you are missing too the option `output-dir`:

```
:output-dir "out"
```

Here is a nice briefing on the compiler options and characteristics: http://slides.com/joakino/diving-into-clojurescript/#/5 (Go down in the slides)

Then in your main file, you need to set a main function and it is nice to enable console prints:

```
(ns cljs-gulp.core
  (:require [cljs.nodejs :as nodejs]))

(nodejs/enable-util-print!)

(defn -main [& args] ... )

(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

Then, you can actually use any mode in nodejs, but the ones that work by default are `simple` and `advanced`. For `none` you need a wrapper file to make node be able to load closure dependencies, so create a file named `index.js` for example and put this in:

```
require('./out/goog/bootstrap/nodejs')
require('./cljs_gulp') // Name of the js ouput file
require('./out/cljs_gulp/core') // Path to compiled core file
cljs_gulp.core._main() // appname.namespace._mainfunction
```

And after compiling you would `node index.js` instead of `node cljs_gulp.js`. And that works awesome, and you take advantage of the super fast recompilation times.

This article explains it all pretty well, and it's recent: http://blog.lauripesonen.com/clojurescript-optimizations-on-node-huh/

Here is the code: (my project name was generated as cljs_gulp, so change that to fit yours)

project.clj

```
(defproject cljs_gulp "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Where I want to learn about clojurescript"
  :url "http://example.com"

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0-alpha2"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2322"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.4-SNAPSHOT"]]

  :source-paths ["src"]

  :cljsbuild {
              :builds [{:id "gulpjs"
                        :source-paths ["src/cljs_gulp/"]
                        :compiler {
                                   :target :nodejs
                                   :output-to "cljs_gulp.js"
                                   :output-dir "out"
                                   :optimizations :none
                                   :pretty-print true}}]})
```

src/cljs_gulp/core.cljs

```
(ns cljs-gulp.core
  (:require [cljs.nodejs :as nodejs]))

(nodejs/enable-util-print!)

(def gulp (nodejs/require "gulp"))

(def gulp-livereload (nodejs/require "gulp-livereload"))

(def gulp-markdown (nodejs/require "gulp-markdown"))

(def gulp-watch (nodejs/require "gulp-watch"))

(defn -main [& args]
  (.task gulp "markdown"
         #(-> (.source gulp "../markdown-explained")
              (.pipe (gulp-markdown))
              (.pipe (.dest gulp "build/markdown-explained")))))

(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

There are a couple of cljs node templates that are very helpful for getting started on cljs and node, instead of the browser:

- https://github.com/swannodette/mies-node-template (most recent and complete one)
- https://github.com/liwp/nodecljs-template
- https://github.com/honza/cljs-node

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you're using `:optimization :none`.

This mode is aimed for active development with a rapid recompilation. That way `cljsbuild` could recompile only the file you've changed without touching other stuff.

If you want to get a single js file, you should use either of following:

```
:optimizations :simple
:optimizations :advanced
```

This will take much more time but creates a single file with all dependencies included.

`:advanced` mode will also clean dead code for you, thus making the target file even smaller.
But you should be careful using it, due to it have some pitfalls by the nature of closure compiler nicely described [in this article](http://lukevanderhart.com/2011/09/30/using-javascript-and-clojurescript.html).

Comment: tks bro, your answer is correct but @Joaquin answer is more thoughtful and great either :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answers, ClojureScript is compiled to browser and in development mode by default. To make sure it's compiled to Node.js , you need to specify `:target :nodejs` somewhere in the configurations.

I want to added that `lein-cljs` is not the only compiler tool for ClojureScript. shadow-cljs can be a better solution if you try https://github.com/minimal-xyz/minimal-shadow-cljs-nodejs .

Besides, the code compiled from ClojureScript is written in Closure JS, which is using `goog.x.y.z` for creating its module system. So you have to bare the fact that the code looks far less like CommonJS. However you can use shadow-cljs and specify `:target :commonjs` if you insist.